# payment faild due to session expired

Tags: android

I am not able to integrate paytm. I got the following error.

> “An Oops! momentPayment failed due to any of these reasons: Session
>   expired due to inactivity You double-clicked on a button Our system
>   encountered an obstacle You can fix it yourself! Here’s how:Clear
>   cookies & temporary internet files of the browser
>
> Check payment status with your bank to avoid double paymentLaunch a
>   new browser & start from the beginning
>
> Still unable to transact? visit us at paytm.com/care”

Please help